# How to automatically sync files between two computers (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, sync, automation

How can i automatically sync files between two windows 10 computers every time a change is made?

- computers are not in the same network
- i need to choose exactly from which folder(PC1) will be files synced
- the same for to folder(PC2)
- the sync needs to go only one way -> PC1 to PC2

Thank you in advance for your help!

Filip